# how do I use google analytics for my J2ME application

Tags: java, java-me, google-analytics

I am trying to integrate Google analytics for my S40 java and Android applications.

Fortunately I am done with Android but I am not able to integrate it on S40 java applications.

I found one java library called googleanalytics-me-2.0.jar from [Projects Kenai](http://kenai.com/projects/googleanalyticsme/downloads)

and modified my code like this..

```
private void initialize() {                                         
    Tracker tracker = Tracker.getInstance(this, "UA-29846745-1");
    tracker.addToQueue(new PageView("/midlet_started"));
}

public void exitMIDlet() {
    switchDisplayable(null, null);
    destroyApp(true);
    Tracker tracker = Tracker.getInstance(this, "UA-29846745-1");
    tracker.flush(false);
    notifyDestroyed();
}
```

but I don't know why I am not able to get any kind of impressions or hit record in my google analytics account.

I have got hits report for Android app but I am not getting any report for my java app.

Please help me in fixing this bug. And if you know any other java library for google analytics please let me know.

Comment: There is a new version available 2.1 http://j2megroup.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/new-version-of-google-analytics-me-v21.html Did you give it a try?